# Update is setting value to null in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 2.2.4 and I'm running into very strange behavior.

Given the following code snippet:

```
var warrantyRegistrationId = warrantyRegistration.Id;  // warrantyRegistration.Id = 20

var order = ctx.Orders  // Id = 13
    .Where(x => x.CompanyId == 1 && x.CustomerId == warrantyRegistrationModel.CustomerId && x.IsDeleted == false && x.WarrantyRegistrationId == null)
    .FirstOrDefault();

var originalOrder = ctx.Orders    // Id = 12
    .Where(x => x.Id == order.OriginalOrderId)
    .FirstOrDefault();

order.WarrantyRegistrationId = warrantyRegistrationId; // order.WarrantyRegistrationId = 20
originalOrder.WarrantyRegistrationId = warrantyRegistrationId;  // originalOrder.WarrantyRegistrationId = 20
ctx.SaveChanges();  

// order.WarrantyRegistrationId = null, originalOrder.WarrantyRegistrationId = 20
```

Somehow the first assignment `order.WarrantyRegistrationId = warrantyRegistrationId;` is being set to null in the database.

When I run Sql Server profiler, I see the following:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [Orders] SET [WarrantyRegistrationId] = @p0
WHERE [Id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
',N'@p1 int,@p0 int',@p1=12,@p0=20
```

and

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [Orders] SET [WarrantyRegistrationId] = @p0
WHERE [Id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
',N'@p1 int,@p0 int',@p1=13,@p0=NULL
```

I'm stuck and can't figure out why this is happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody else runs into this, here's the answer.

I had set this as `.HasOne().WithOne()`, which created a unique index on WarrantyRegistrationId.  Since I was assigning a new Id, it was removing it from the previous WarrantyRegistrationId to keep it unique.

I changed this to `.HasOne().WithMany()` and it's working now.